# Serverless: You're using the LAMBDA-PROXY in combination with request / response

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework

Could someone please help explain what this warning message means?

***Serverless: Warning! You're using the LAMBDA-PROXY in combination with request / response configuration in your function "indexPage". This configuration will be ignored during deployment.***

I believe I understand the LAMDA-PROXY part. I'm pretty sure this is a reference to the "Integration" section of the serverless.yml:

```
 indexPage:
    handler: reporting.index
    memorySize: 128
    timeout: 15
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: post
          integration: lambda-proxy
          response:
           headers:
             Content-Type: "'text/html'"
           template: $input.path('$')
```

I have no idea what it is referencing with the "request / response configuration".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use lambda-proxy you return everything through your lambda function, not the configuration. It says that it will ignore this part:

```
response:
       headers:
         Content-Type: "'text/html'"
       template: $input.path('$')
```

If you want to define request/response in your configuration file you need to change your integration to lambda from lambda-proxy.